# UITableView - transparent background in iOS 7

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I am checking my app with ios 7 beta. I have set background color of `UITableView` to clear color. Its still showing white background. 
Is there any other way around to make it transparant?

Comment: I disagree with this being closed. It is very relevant. I for one would like to answer the question.

Comment: You need to use the tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: delegate method to set features of cells within the Table. Especially if you are using old nibs from some older project.

Comment: Indeed a very questionable decision to close this question - why is this too localized??? And please also look at the > 11000 times viewed in 3 months ...

Comment: iOS 7 was under NDA when this question was posted. That is probably why it was closed. This person should have have been asking questions about a product for which they signed an NDA.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting tableview backgroundColor to clear color working absolutely fine in iOS 7 chk [image: this] 
 screenshot see those separator lines for the table cells while the tableview is transparent.

Comment: Got It, I set clear color to tableview background but also need to set clear color for tableviewcells.Thanks!

Comment: Thank for that. Just to give my two cents, in iOS 6 or older, the default background was transparent, it is why without changing something, you still have transparent in iOS 6 and you got the white background on iOS. So just make all clear color to be sure it is everywhere.

Comment: Actually, I am having the exact same problem, even tough the UITableViewCell and all the relevant UIViews within it are set to clearColor.

Comment: I was having that problem too, i'm using a custom cell loaded from nib, setting it's background color in interface builder to clear still resulted in a white background. I fixed it by setting the background color to clear in `cellForRow`...

Comment: @Allwood, same fix for me, tried for hours within IB, then solved by adding clearColor directly into the application code.

Comment: You should set your cell to "setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]" when the cell will be generated inside cellForRowAtIndex. I tried before to set all attributes in the IB to clearColor but it looks like there is a bug in the IDE and it doesn't work at the moment.

Comment: I think doing in IB apparent set the background color for the cell's contentView, which is not what you want. You want to se the background color of the "cell" itself. So, guess have to do it in code to make sure it looks right.

Comment: I have a universal app. For iPhone, setting the `backgroundColor` property in `awakeFromNib` was enough, but for iPad, I had to set not just the `backgroundColor`, but the contentView's background color in both `awakeFromNib`, AND in `setSelected:animated:`. Hope this helps someone. (Note that this is no longer in BETA!)

Comment: Yes as livingtech pointed out the above works fine for iPhone/iPod but for iPad it doesn't work and the background is white. Also, even after setting everything to the same color manually the disclosure indicator still shows up white. Seriously annoyed by apple.

Answer (score 11):

I couldn't make it work but the following worked perfectly :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
 }
```

Comment: Apparently there's an internal flag inside the cell that tracks whether the color has been set or not.  Using `getRed:green:blue:alpha` before and after setting `clearColor` as above yields the same results, yet the above code definitely has the intended effect of converting the cell background from white to clear.

Comment: This is also the perfect place to alternate the background color

Answer (score 8):

Believe it or not, the following statement, added to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, will cause iOS 7 to honor the XIB-specified color:

```
cell.backgroundColor = cell.backgroundColor;
```

Comment: Didn't solve the issue while it's solved by this:

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Answer (score 1):

In my XCode 5 Storyboard I had to set the background color of the 'View' section on the Table View properties to clear as well.

Comment: UITableView extends UIScrollView. It does not have its own scrollView property.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to Storyboards.  There is a section for 'Scroll View' in there: http://screencast.com/t/UauSjNq76g.  Please remove your down vote.

Comment: But it looks like even that isn't what I meant.  I had to set the Background property on the general 'View' section, not Scroll View

Comment: Gotcha. I take it all back then :)